# jquery multiple resize events on one page

Tags: jquery, html, resize, window

I have multiple div's on one page, and each one can be resized via the jquery `.resize()` method.

i need to be able to resize the page as well, and I'm sure the reason i haven't been able to do this is due to my naivety with the jQuery selector mechanism.

my code:

`<div class='droppedElement' blah...>`   (these are the 's that resize nicely now)

i now have,

```
$('.droppedElement').live('mouseenter',function() {
    $(function() {
        $('.droppedElement').resizable(resizeOpts);
    });
});
```

but if i try `$(window).resizable(...)`

i get conflicts, and the browser grinds to a halt.

any ideas?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're wanting the `$(window).resize()` event, and not trying to attach the resizable plugin to the window object, right?

Answer (score 1):

`window` refers to the browser window. That should be resizable by default. jQuery cannot handle that resizing behavior. Can you link an example?

Use `$(window).resize()` to attach a listener to the window resize.